# Variable size in custom views Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, graphics

I'm implementing a custom View and I want to be able of change it size on runtime.

Simplifying the problem: I need to display a Bitmap in this view, but since it is refreshed frequently I'd like to extend SurfaceView.

The problem is that I lose the ImageView's auto resize functionality.

So I want to declare a method setCustomBitmap(Bitmap bmp) and resize (at the moment or the next time the view is displayed) the view dimensions according with that bitmap width and height (keeping the aspect ratio).

What method should I use? I imagine that setWidth() and setHeight() is not the best idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're extending SurfaceView, you might be able to override the `onMeasure()` method. The MeasureSpec instances that you pass to the superclass (via `super.onMeasure()`) will determine the size of the SurfaceView. You can use the dimensions of your Bitmap to make each MeasureSpec.

For example:

```
protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ) {
    int parentViewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize( widthMeasureSpec );
    int parentViewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize( heightMeasureSpec );
    // ... take into account the parent's size as needed ...
    super.onMeasure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( bitmap.width(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( bitmap.height(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );
}
```